# android Imageview hides elements below when changing orientation

Tags: android, imageview, landscape

I'm facing a problem when changing the screen orientation. When the phones in portrait mode everything's working fine but when i change the orientation to landscape mode the imageview hides the button bellow.

Here's my layouts xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:longClickable="false">


<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Your Inbox"
    android:id="@+id/btn_inbox"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_inbox"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/img_main" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Scan QR"
    android:id="@+id/btn_qrscan"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:enabled="false" />
```

Comment: android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" use this line in manifest.xml in your activity place.it sloved my probllme

Answer (score 1):

Sure, because the image could has a size that fits the screen in portrait. If you want to view all, you need to:

- Reduce the size of the imageview
- Play with the property "weight" of the components in the view
- Add a Scrollview if you want to use a scroll

Comment: the weight property is used only for the linearlayout. i tried it but then if i use a fixed layout weight it may work on landscape but doesnt work on portrait mode as it should. maybe i should change it via code when the orientation is changed? what is the best practice? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Its because, the height of the screen in Portrait mode is more, when compared to height of the screen in Landscape mode. The elements won't adjust their places, as per screen height automatically. You should handle the placement of views on all orientations/devices/tablets.

The width is more when the device is in landscape mode. So, try changing the position of views to make use of the width when height is less.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:longClickable="false"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_inbox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Your Inbox" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/background" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_qrscan"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="Scan QR" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. i tried it but then when i change from landscape to portrait mode it still isnt displayed correctly, there's too much of a gap. isnt there a way that i can fit everything to screen while maintaining the correct proportions?

Comment: i have updated with new  xml . can u try this with imageview weight =1

Comment: create a same layout file with same name and put it in layout-land folder with same components with landscape design

Answer (score 0):

I Solved the problem using these line in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
 android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```